# C equivalent of std::endl

Tags: c

C++ has `std::endl`. Does anyone know of anything in C to use for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::endl` has the effect of printing a newline `'\n'` character and then flushing the output stream.

The C equivalent, if you're printing to stdout, would be:

```
putchar('\n');
fflush(stdout);
```

But in most cases the `fflush` is unnecessary.

Note that `std::endl` does *not* have the purpose of providing a platform-independent line ending. The character `'\n'` already is a platform-independent line ending. When written to a text stream, it will be translated to whatever line ending the platform uses (`\r\n` for Windows, just `\n` for Unix, etc.).

Comment: I was mostly looking for a platform-independent line ending, but you make a good point.I didn't realize endl flushes the outputstream but '\n' doesn't necessarily flush stdout.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>

putchar ('\n');   /* To the stdout stream. */
printf ("\n");    /* Ditto. */
```

And for arbitrary streams `fp`,

```
fputc (fp, '\n');
```

This should work for line buffered and unbuffered streams. Fully buffered streams require an `fflush(NULL)` if you want to see the result immediately. So which is which? The gory details from the C99 Standard:

> As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered;
>   the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if
>   and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an
>   interactive device.

Answer (score 2):

`std::endl` flushes the stream but printing newline in C doesn't do that. So you have to use `fflush`.

Comment: In C it is flushed as well for line-buffered and unbuffered streams.